# Increase all primary key values by 1

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-design

How do I increase all of my `EmployeeID` values by one if it is the primary key?

Answer (score 11):

I assume that this question is about how to update a bunch of rows to a value on higher without stepping on each other. If you update id=1 to id=2 in the first row while the second row (with id=2) is still there you will get a primary key violation because now you have two rows with id=2.

To prevent that type of collision you just need to start at the largest value and increase it by one. that opens up a gap for the second largest value to move into which in turn opens a gap for the third largest value to move into, and so on.

In SQL Server however, you need not worry, as the engine is taking care of that automatically:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6d08fd/5)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Employee(Id INT PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, Name NVARCHAR(MAX));

INSERT INTO dbo.Employee(Id,Name)
VALUES(1,'John'),(2,'Jane'),(3,'Max');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Employee;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6d08fd/5/0)**:

```
| ID | NAME |
|----|------|
|  1 | John |
|  2 | Jane |
|  3 |  Max |
```

**Query 2**:

```
UPDATE dbo.Employee
  SET Id = Id + 1;
```

**[Execution Plan](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6d08fd/5/1)**

**Query 3**:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Employee;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6d08fd/5/2)**:

```
| ID | NAME |
|----|------|
|  2 | John |
|  3 | Jane |
|  4 |  Max |
```

**Query 4**:

```
UPDATE dbo.Employee
  SET Id = Id - 1;
```

**[Execution Plan](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6d08fd/5/3)**

**Query 5**:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Employee;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6d08fd/5/4)**:

```
| ID | NAME |
|----|------|
|  1 | John |
|  2 | Jane |
|  3 |  Max |
```

If you actually follow the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6d08fd/5) link, you can also see the execution plans for the two update statements. The first one looks like this:

[image]

There you can see fairly far to the left a `Table Spool` operator. That operator basically creates a copy of all rows that were updated before they get written back by the actual `Clustered Index Update' operator next to it. Because of this SQL Server is able to handle "overlapping" updates without tripping over itself.

An added benefit (and the original reason why this behavior was implemented) is that this two step approach provides [Halloween Protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/craigfr/halloween-protection?Redirected=true).

Comment: The table spool is needed because the name column is a LOB type. With a non-LOB name, the sort provides sufficient phase separation for HP. The Split-Sort-Collapse optimizes logging and ensures changes are applied in an order that prevents transient key violations.

Comment: @PaulWhite, thanks for the clarifying comment. You are bringing up quite a few concepts in your short sentence above. Does one of you articles go into more detail?

Comment: I had to check, but yes! I discuss Split-Sort-Collapse in [this post](https://sqlkiwi.blogspot.com/2010/12/beware-sneaky-reads-with-unique-indexes.html) and Halloween Protection in a [four-part series](https://sqlkiwi.blogspot.com/2013/02/halloween-protection-the-complete-series.html). Conor Cunningham talks about the logging optimization in his chapter of the SQL Server 2008 Internals book from MS Press.

Answer (score 5):

Without more detail about the structure of your database there are a large number of variables here.

If any other table that contains the employee IDs as reference to this table and forgeign keys are properly setup and set to `ON UPDATE CASCADE` then simply executing `UPDATE EmployeeTable SET EmployeeID = EmployeeID + 1` will do the trick - the FK relationships will update everything else as needed. Without `ON UPDATE CASCADE` in this case you will get errors and the statement will fail.

If you have tables that refer to the employee ID without forgeign key constraints being present then you will have to update those too with `UPDATE AnotherTable SET EmployeeID = EmployeeID + 1`. You should wrap all the table updates in a single transaction (with error handling to make sure the transaction is rolled back or `SET XACT_ABORT ON` if you don't need any finer control over that process) in order to maintain consistency (so if something fails everything is rolled back).

I would question why you would ever want to do this though. An employee identifier is generally a surrogate key (also called a pseudo key) that carries no meaning aside from identifying a given person (it could eaily be a UUID insead of a number, except for the fact it is likely used in real-world written down, so a UUID would not be convenient). See the "psuedo-key neat-freak" chapter in SQL Antipatterns for more discussion on this.